# sum data of histogram with python

Tags: python, numpy, charts, histogram

i have a data of;

```
profile_bucket | price
a          10
b          15
c          5
a          7
c          20
```

doing hist chart with this kind of data, but hist gives me a count of the values, but I need the sum of the price instead of the count. any ideas? Using py.

Comment: You can try `df = df.groupby('profile_bucket').sum()` and after that plot with `df['price']`

Comment: didnt get it? can you explain

Comment: Refer to my answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'profile_bucket':['a','b','c','a','c'], 'price':[10,15,5,7,20]})
df = df.groupby('profile_bucket').sum()
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

Output:

```
    profile_bucket  price
0   a   17
1   b   15
2   c   25
```

[image]

Comment: is that it? i want to have histogram out of this output how am I going to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Because histogram is to bin the data `df['price']` and count the number of values in each bin, so if you want to sum the **price**, use bar chart instead:

```
d = {'profile_bucket': ['a','b','c','a','c'], 'price': [10,15,5,7,20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df2 = df.groupby('profile_bucket').sum()
df2.plot(kind='bar')
```

Output:

[image]